# dask.distributed: wait for all tasks to finish before shutdown (without futures)

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

**Tldr:**

I'm using `fire_and_forget` to execute tasks on a `dask.distributed` cluster, so I don't maintain a future for each task. How can I wait until they are all done before the cluster gets shut down?

**Details:**

I have a workflow that creates a `xarray` dataset which is persisted on the cluster. Once the computations are done, I want to save the time slices individually and move on to the next dataset.

Until now, I've been using a `delayed` function and collected a list of delayed tasks which I then passed on to `client.compute` - this way I was sure everything was done before I moved on to the next dataset. The downside is, that all is blocked until every last file got written.

Now I'm looking into `fire_and_forget` to be able to start the computations on the next dataset while the files of the previous one are still being written.

I'm planning to `wait` for each dataset to be completed before I start the `fire_and_forget` tasks, so they should have plenty of time to complete.
The only issue I've encountered is, that when processing the last dataset, there's no more waiting and the cluster gets shut down after the last `fire_and_forget` call, even though the processes are still running.

So is there any way to tell the client it needs to block until all is completed?

Or am I maybe not properly understanding the use of `fire_and_forget` and should stay with my previous approach?

Here's an example code that simulates the workflow - it does 10 iterations (simulating the different datasets) and then writes the first 10 time slices to pickle files. So in the end I'm expecting 100 pickle files on disk, which is not the case.

```py
import pickle
import random
from time import sleep

from dask import delayed
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client, wait, fire_and_forget
import xarray as xr

@delayed
def dump_delayed(x, fn):
    with open(fn, "wb") as f:
        random.seed(42)
        sleep(random.randint(1,2))
        pickle.dump(x, f)

TARGET = "/home/jovyan/"

def main():

    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=2, ip="0.0.0.0")
    client = Client(cluster)

    ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("rasm")

    for it in range(1,10):
        print("Iteration %s" % it)

        # simulating the processing and persisting
        ds2 = (ds*it).chunk({"time": 1}).persist()
        _ = wait(ds2)
    
        for ii in range(10):
            
            fn = TARGET + f"temp{ii}_{it}.pkl"
            xx = ds2.isel(time=ii)
            
            f = client.persist(dump_delayed(xx, fn))
            fire_and_forget(f)
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this qualifies for a solution, but `fire_and_forget` is for a specific use case where you do not want to track the status of the task. If you are interested in the status of the tasks, it's better to use the regular `future`.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to track the status - I just don't want the cluster to shut down before all `fire_and_forget`s completed ...

Comment: As a simple hack you could have a wait loop that checks whether all the files have been written, but, as per above, you are much better off explicitly tracking futures, because then you can use `distributed.wait()` which will wait for those futures to complete.

Comment: I was hoping for a dask-native solution. I have a working alternative, I'm looking for an improvement (which I thought I can get with `fire_and_forget`). I could also collect the futures in a list and `wait` in the end until all are done, but that would keep a reference to every dataset, which is exactly what I _not_ want.

Comment: Well, you can always delete (i.e. `release`) the completed futures within an `as_completed` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this could work indeed. Would be probably be still bit hacky, and no real upside to the existing solution ... I guess the real gist of this question is, _can I do it with fire_and_forget_?